# How can I get tooltip to hover on top of texboxes?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hello again dearest Experts,
I am still having issues getting tooltips to work correctly.

The code below works correctly as far displaying the tooltips.

The big issue is that it expands the textbox, making other textboxes lose alignment.

What we would like to is to have the message in the tooltop hover on top of the textbox but not obscure it. This way, users can still type into it.

Can the code I have below be modified to help me accomplish this?

Many thanks.

THe css

```
<style type="text/css">
div.activeToolTip 
{
 display:block;
 visibility:visible;
 background-color:#A1D40A;
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.75em;
 line-height: 1.50em;
 font-weight:bold;
 color: #fff;
 border:1px solid black;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=gray,direction=135);
 width:200px;
 height:70px;
}
div.idleToolTip 
{
 display:none;
 visibility:hidden;
}
```

Then textbox and tooltip.

```
 <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="instruct" onmouseover="document.getElementById('toolTipDiv').className='activeToolTip'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('toolTipDiv').className='idleToolTip'" runat="server" Width="75px"></asp:TextBox>
 <div id="toolTipDiv" class="idleToolTip">My instructions go here.</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to make your tooltip `position: absolute`.  This way you'll have exact control over where it appears and it won't affect the layout of any other elements.

The other thing you should do it put it in an element with `position: relative` set:

```
<div class="relative">
    <input type="text" />
    <div id="toolTipDiv" class="idleToolTip">My instructions go here.</div>
</div>
```

This will create the coordinate system for it (i.e.: `bottom: 20px` will translate to 20px from the bottom of the relative parent):

```
.relative {
    position: relative;
}

#toolTipDiv {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px; 
    left: 0;

}
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aq3MK/) of it in action.

Comment: THANK YOU ALL Dearest Experts. Pat's solution worked perfectly for me. May you ALL receive infinite Blessings for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

**edit:** sorry, that was a complete brain fart. I need more sleep. `display:absolute` won't do anything, it's `position:absolute`

Can you show the problem in the jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use a jQuery plugin, there are tons of them:

[30 Stylish jQuery Tooltip Plugins For Catchy Designs](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/)